# How to do validation while databinding?

Tags: winforms

How can I do validation and stop databinding when validation failed?

for example, if a user type 1234 for a firstName texbox which has the following binding:
 this.textBoxFirstName.DataBindings.Add("Text", personObj, "FirstName");

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use [BindingComplete](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.binding.bindingcomplete.aspx) and/or [Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.binding.parse.aspx) events of `Binding` class.

Or use control's validation functionality, which is preferable. 
Or use some kind of mask editor. Mask editor would be better from the usability point of view.